# How to extract last month of dynamic table from database

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, datatable

In one database, there are 12 different dynamic tables are present. Ex-

```
arch_tbl_jan
arch_tbl_feb
arch_tbl_mar
arch_tbl_apr
arch_tbl_may
arch_tbl_jun
arch_tbl_jul
arch_tbl_aug
arch_tbl_sep
arch_tbl_oct
arch_tbl_nov
arch_tbl_dec
```

These 12 dynamic tables are exist in one database under schema. I want to extract in `SELECT` statement as per the month basis. For ex- for **APRIL** month, I want to extract **MARCH** month of table (**arch_tbl_mar**), for **JUNE** want to extract **MAY** month of table (**arch_tbl_may**). How can i extract these dynamic tables as per month basis. 
Select statement like-

```
select id, name from arch_tbl_jan;   --(In Feb month)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Oracle 12c and above, use `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` with a dynamic cursor. The table name gets automatically assigned based on the date of run using `ADD_MONTHS, SYSDATE` and `TO_CHAR`.

```
declare
   x SYS_REFCURSOR;
   l_table_name varchar2(40) := 'arch_tbl_' 
                                 || TO_CHAR( add_months(sysdate,-1),'fmMON');
BEGIN
     OPEN x FOR 'SELECT * FROM ' || l_table_name;
     DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(x);
END;
/
```

For 11g, `RETURN_RESULT` can be implemented using `DBMS_SQL` by passing a query instead of `ref cursor`. 
Here's an example for that : [**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=252ebce85d87de49b8e7a875c48edb5f)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare 
 v_sql varchar2(10000);
 l_table_name varchar2(40) := 'arch_tbl_' 
                             || TO_CHAR( add_months(sysdate,-1),'MON');
BEGIN
 v_sql := 'select .. into ....... from ' || l_table_name || ' .... ';
 execute immediate v_sql;
 commit;
END;
```

Comment: You aren't selecting *into* anything, so the query won't actually be executed; and if you did select into something then you'd need to display it somehow. Opening a refcursor seems rather simpler.